# How does the size of a canvas affect it's memory usage?

Tags: canvas

My question is, how does the size of a canvas affect it's memory usage? Let's say I have two canvases, one that is 10 000 x 10 000 pixels and one that is 1000 x 1000 pixels. On both canvases, I draw an image that is 1000 x 1000 pixels. Will the larger canvas use (significally) more memory than the smaller canvas, even though the size of the drawing is the same?

In my application, I have a canvas that is precisely the size of the image that is currently being drawn on it. I'm considering making the canvas bigger and only draw on a small portion of the canvas, but I'm curious how it would affect memory usage.

Comment: Empty pixels still exist, so yep, your 10K canvas will take (a lot) more memory.

Comment: Every canvas stores every pixel as 4 8-bit integers, so your canvas memory size would always be 4 * width * height bytes. That is the smallest configuration a canvas can stores it's image in.

Comment: I see! Thank you both for answering my question.